# How to check if class type A extends class type B in groovy

Tags: groovy

**How to check if class type B extends class type A in groovy?**

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Groovy's `in` operator will test for the **is a** relationship when the right-hand argument is a Class, so `B in A` is equivalent to Java's `A.isAssignableFrom(B)`. This also works for objects. `new C() in A` is equivalent to `new C() instanceof A`.

#### Example

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

assert C in A // C inherits from A

interface I {}
interface J extends I{}

assert J in I // J extends I

class D implements I {}

assert D in I // D implements I

final o = new C()
assert o in A // o is an instance of A
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it the same way as in Java:

```
A.isAssignableFrom(B)
```

*See another [Justin Piper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052417/how-to-check-if-class-type-a-extends-class-type-b-in-groovy/19059384#19059384) for Groovy `in` operator.*

It seems awkward, but it means that **B is a subclass of A**. The height of inheritance hierarchy does not matter. It works also in case of interfaces.

#### Example

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

assert A.isAssignableFrom(C) // C inherits from A

interface I {}
interface J extends I{}

assert I.isAssignableFrom(J) // J extends I

class D implements I {}

assert I.isAssignableFrom(D) // D implements I
```

See [Class.isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: In Groovy you could write this less awkwardly and more concisely using the `in` operator: `assert C in A`. Works for objects too: `assert new C() in A`.

Comment: @JustinPiper It's worth another answer. Would you add it?

Comment: Happy to. I used your examples to show the symmetry between the Java and Groovy versions. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: If you plan to use `isAssignableFrom()` on an existing object, be sure to pass the objects class instead of the object itself (myObj`.getClass()`) or you risk `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [...].isAssignableFrom() is applicable for argument types: (...) values: [...]`

Answer (score 2):

If it's just direct inheritance you're concerned with, java.lang.Class' `getSuperclass` method should do the trick:

```
assert B.superclass == A
```

Applying a little Groovy magic to @Grzegorz's answer, you could do this to add a more readable method to the Class type:

```
class ClassHelper {
    static boolean extendsFrom(Class sub, cls) {
        cls.isAssignableFrom(sub)
    }
}

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

use(ClassHelper) {
    assert B.extendsFrom(A)
    assert C.extendsFrom(B)
    assert C.extendsFrom(A)
    assert !B.extendsFrom(C)
}
```

Comment: It would be valid only for direct inheritance. If you add C extending B. Then `C.superclass == A` will fail.

Comment: Right, that's why I qualified the answer with 'if it's just direct inheritance you're concerned with'